# Which characters can be used in an attribute name? - FIWARE Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'd like to know details about character set and character code that can be used in an attribute name. I tried to create an entity that has an attribute name "日本語". I was able to create it in case of NGSIv1 but not in case of NGSIv2.

- In case of NGSIv1 API,

Request:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/updateContext -sS --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- <<EOF) | jq .
{
  "contextElements": [
    {
      "type": "Test",
      "isPattern": "false",
      "id": "Testv1",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "japanese",
          "type": "Integer",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "日本語",
          "type": "Integer",
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
EOF
```

Response:

```
{
  "contextResponses": [
    {
      "contextElement": {
        "type": "Test",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "Testv1",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "japanese",
            "type": "Integer",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "日本語",
            "type": "Integer",
            "value": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode": {
        "code": "200",
        "reasonPhrase": "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- In case of NGSIv2 API,

Request:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v2/entities -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d @- <<EOF) | jq .
{
  "id": "Test1",
  "type": "Test",
  "japanese": {
    "value": 1,
    "type": "Integer"
  },
  "日本語": {
    "value": 2,
    "type": "Integer"
  }
}
EOF
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": "BadRequest",
  "description": "Invalid characters in attribute name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant sections in [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) regarding allowed characters are "Field syntax restrictions", "Attribute names restrictions" and "Metadata names restrictions".

In particular, related with the topic of this question:

> Allowed characters are the ones in the plain ASCII set, except the following ones: control characters, whitespace, `&`, `?`, `/` and `#`.

Note also

> In addition to the above rules, given NGSIv2 server implementations could add additional syntactical restrictions in those or other fields, e.g., to avoid cross script injection attacks.

which, in the case of Orion it's specified as part of its documentation [here](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! I understood.